# Embedded a video in angular with iframe

Tags: angular, video, iframe

I want to include a video to the angular app. Video URL is taking from API. I tried below:

```
<iframe src="{{videoUrl}}" width="320" height="200">
```

This 'videoUrl' is the parameter which I taken from the API. But this is not working. If I use my own URL it is working.

```
<iframe src="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Vt-Wf7d0CFo" width="320"`height="200">
```

This is working.

I print `videoUrl` separately to check weather data is coming or not. Data also coming fine.

Can someone help me to resolve this issue?

Comment: If `iframe src="{{videoUrl}}"` then what happens if `var videoUrl = "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Vt-Wf7d0CFo";`?

Comment: **(1)** Not clear what is `{{videoUrl}}` ... Is it some HTML text (for a web page)? Is that why you are using it inside an iFrame? If it points to a real video file then try using a `<video>` tag, instead of using `<iframe>`. **(2)** Test by making `{{videoUrl}}` point to the working Youtube link. What happens when you `console.log` the `{{videoUrl}}` variable? Is it showing text of the Youtube URL or showing something else?